# What is CMS/Framework used in both of this website?

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system

Both of this website has similar feature and interface, so I have strong feeling that both of this website built on same CMS/framework:
`lintasberita.com`
`cekberita.com`

Its built on PHP
But What is the CMS/Framework used by that website?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> `<meta name="description" content="Hotaru CMS is an open source content management system, written in PHP." />`

Although having looked at that source code, I'm not seeing anything to encourage me to use it.

Of course, the multiple `<script>` elements, comment before the Doctype, meta description designed to wreck listings in Google, invalid HTML and hideous design could be the author's fault…

Answer (score 0):

In the page source of [cekberita.com](http://cekberita.com), there was written in a meta tag: "Hotaru CMS is an open source content management system, written in PHP." So I guess it is Hotaru.